# Spinor rotation around the $z$-axis

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, group-representations, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

In Schwartz's QFT textbook (eq. 10.118), he gives the equation for the Lorentz transformation matrix of a rotation around the $z$-axis for as spinor as
$$
\Lambda_s(\theta_z)=\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\exp({i\over 2}\theta_z)& & & \\
&\exp({-i\over 2}\theta_z) & & \\
& & \exp({i\over 2}\theta_z)& \\
& & & \exp({-i\over 2}\theta_z)\\
\end{array} 
\right) \tag{10.118}
$$
He then states on pg 176 that $\Lambda_s(\pi)=i$ for each spinor. I don't understand this as from the above equation shouldn't it be:
$$
\Lambda_s(\pi)=\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
i& & & \\
&-i& & \\
& & i& \\
& & & -i\\
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Lambda_s(\pi)$ is certainly not $i$ in general. However, on that page Schwartz applies this to the z-spin up particles. In which case it acts as multiplying by $i$.